# Relationship to self in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to create friends list in my core Data. I have entity `User` with `relationship friends`. My user have `attributes` (to simplify):

- userId
- name

I want that he can make friends so i add this relationship:

[image]

All friends of course will be have the same pair of attribute.

So when i look into graph i see something like this:

[image]

This is correct ? Can i managed it like separate entity? Will creating a new friend create a new user? What is **keyword** for apple documentation to find an example or description of this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship is absolutely correct, except that friendship is naturally bidirectional, so inverse relation is friends too. There is no such issue as creating a friend, so it not creates a new user. You can just build a friendship relation between two existing users.
The keyword you are looking for is : Core Data Programming Guide :)

Comment: Why need inversion relationship ?

Comment: Old but I'll answer in case someone falls on this - adding a reverse relationship is important for Core Data to maintain a valid object graph. You should always add an inverse relationship. What's nice is that Core Data will automatically create the reverse relationship automatically (i.e. `Person` has a `Dog`, setting `personA.dog = dog` will automatically set `dog`'s `Person` relationship.

Comment: Another four years later, I'll add that specifying the inverse relationship seems to be required when defining a recursive relationship with SwiftData.